# Change list behavior: Clicking list item SELECTS item rather than opening display page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, web-part-page

**Context:** 
 I have a requirement for a list that contains public and private data. The 'solutions' I found are mostly security through obscurity (views, web part trickiness etc) and not appropriate for my environment. The solution I have chosen is to create two lists, with private information linked to public table using a lookup column. I then have a web part page showing both lists, with connections enabled so when a user selects an item in the public list, the corresponding entry in the private list displays (only if they are in a group that has access to private).

**Problem:** 
Although the solution is functional, the navigation is clunky and not intuitive to users. To select a list item they must click a tiny connection icon at the left. If they click elsewhere in the list, the item is highlighted however the  linked list is not refreshed based on the selection.

**Objective:** 
When users click ANY field in the public list, it selects the list item and updates the filter, refreshing the connected (private) list. I found a solution while researching but it seems to be for a different version. Bonus points if it is possible to CTRL+Click to select multiple items simultaneously.

**Constraints:**
- It is not possible to use scripting or Power Shell.

So what do you think exchangers? Possible?

Comment: So to me it sounds like they are clicking the "Name" field in the list which is liked to the display form. I would adjust your view so that instead of having the "Name (linked to item with edit menu) " field you add the standalone Name field. This will remove the hyperlink behind the item. And clicking on any of the fields will just select the item.

Comment: Thanks Ramana - I'm halfway there! Removing the 'title' column from the view stops the display popup, however clicking elsewhere does not refresh the connection to the linked list.  Question edited for clarity.